# I can't change string when I use beautifulsoup.The string is auto encodes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the <>is auto encodes.

Please helpe me ,thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a **more semantical way**, with `Tag.new_tag(..)`, `Tag.clear()` and `Tag.append()`:

```
atag = soup.a
atag.clear() # clear the content of the <a> tag
atag.append('support') # add the 'support' text
emtag = soup.new_tag('em') # create a new <em> tag
atag.append(emtag) # add the <em> tag to the <a> tag
emtag.string = '[6666]' # alter the text in the <em> tag
```

This constructs:

```
>>> soup
<html><body><a href="#" onclick="foo">support<em>[6666]</em></a></body></html>
```

On my machine.